# How to exclude or remove specific items from snapshot.data.documents?

Tags: flutter

```
final List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = snapshot.data.documents
.where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['username'] != "John123145").toList();
```

this works with excluding specific username with value "John123145".

Question is how can I exclude 2 or more username?

```
List<String> listitems= ["John", "James"];
final List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = snapshot.data.documents
.where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['username'] != listitems).toList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
List<String> listitems= ["John", "James"];
final List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = snapshot.data.documents.where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  return !listitems.contains(documentSnapshot['username'])
}).toList();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this;

```
List<String> listitems= ["John", "James"];
final List<DocumentSnapshot> userList = snapshot.data.documents
.where((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) => listItem.indexOf(documentSnapshot['username'] > -1)).toList();
```

the method **indexOf** searcha a list for a given value, returns the index of the item if found, if not, it will return -1; so we are checking for it to be greater than -1 to be true. then it gets removed from the snapshot data.